# Find over an Unsorted vector<int>

Tags: c++, vector, stl, find

I need to apply a *FIND* functionality over vector elements (similar to the *MATLAB FIND* command) returning all ocurrences. While being unable to find this using the *STL* functions with iterators, i concocted this function:

```
vector<int> find(vector<int> v, int value,vector<int>*ive)
{
    //Generic Find
    vector<int> ve;
    for (int i=0;i<v.size();i++)
    {
        if (v[i]==value)
        {
            ive->push_back(i);
            ve.push_back(v[i]);
        }
    }
return ve;
}
```

called with:

```
//Values
vector<int> v1 = {1,3,3,4,5,2,3,4,6,7,7,8,1,2,2,3,2,2,3,2};
vector<int> iRange,vRange;
int val=2;

//Manual FIND
vRange=find(v1,val,&iRange);
PrintArray(vRange);
PrintArray(iRange);
```

Returning the correct result:

```
vRange: 2 2 2 2 2 2 
iRange: 5 13 14 16 17 19
```

Which of course do not use the *pair* object, the *sort()* and *equal_range()* function, which would be the ideal:

```
pair<vector<int>::iterator,vector<int>::iterator> Range;
sort(v1.begin(),v1.end());
Range=equal_range(v1.begin(),v1.end(),val);
```

Returning the *absolutely proper*, but so far **totally useless** result, if one wishes the result over the original, unsorted vector:

```
Range Iters: 2 2 2 2 2 2 
Range:       2 3 4 5 6 7
```

How should i use STL for this?

Thanks,
hyp

Comment: You want to retain the original `std::vector<int>` in its original order but return a subrange representing only a choice of objects? This won't work! You can either reorder the original vector and return iterators to the selected subrange or you'll need a copy of the subrange. You can't have both.

Comment: Yes!. But i was unable to make the function to pass the iterators out of the function. Make a FIND function seem to be a bit 'complex'.....

Comment: Adding a dimension to the vector to keep the order would be a solution, but i dont know how the _sort_ works with that...

Comment: What do you intend to do with the result?

Comment: When the STL doesn't have the functionality you need there's nothing wrong with writing your own function that does.

Comment: why don't you keep it simple as you have already done?!

Comment: I actually want to learn what is the standard approach. 'My normal approach is useless here'. On MATLAB you always have a _find_ returning all the instances and i intend to apply this _find_ several times, for several purposes. If there is no better choice, i will use the above function :)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your problem (and that is a **big** "if"), I *think* this will do what you're looking for:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>
#include <type_traits>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

template<typename Iterator>
std::vector<std::pair<Iterator, typename std::iterator_traits<Iterator>::difference_type>> find_range
(
    Iterator begin,
    Iterator end,
    const typename std::iterator_traits<Iterator>::value_type& val
)
{
    std::vector<std::pair<Iterator, typename std::iterator_traits<Iterator>::difference_type>> res;
    for (Iterator it = std::find(begin, end, val);
         it != end; it = std::find(std::next(it), end, val))
        res.push_back(std::make_pair(it, std::distance(begin, it)));
    return res;
};

int main()
{
    vector<int> v1 = {1,3,3,4,5,2,3,4,6,7,7,8,1,2,2,3,2,2,3,2};

    auto res = find_range(v1.cbegin(), v1.cend(), 2);
    for (auto obj : res)
        std::cout << *obj.first << ':' << obj.second << std::endl;

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

**Output**

```
2:5
2:13
2:14
2:16
2:17
2:19
```

Each element in the resulting vector is a pair containing the iterator where the value was found, and a difference-type compatible value that corresponds to the distance from the beginning iterator. This should work with any sequence container providing a valid forward-iterator (const or otherwise).

Of course, you can do the same thing by simply returning a `std::vector<>` with offsets and do the math via `std::advance`, but that could get expensive. You've already walked the line once already. No need to do it again (and again...).

Hope this is what you were looking for.

Comment: A huge thanks!. Honestly, i dont understand your code. But it works fine. It contains all things i currently want to do, so i will try to extend it to a matrix version of it. See you

Comment: Sorry i didn't sit on this answer after posting it. I'll try and get some time to write up the description, step by step, of what it is doing. The api's from the standard library are fairly straight-forward, however. You obviously know what `std::find()` does. `std::next(it)` simply returns the iterator *following* `it`. `std::distance()` is simply a magnitude (counter) of "items" between two iterators. All this really does is find the next occurrence of the value-param, then makes a `pair from the resulting iterator and that iterator's distance from `begin`.